# DOCUSIGN REST API: Search by title/name of Envelope

Tags: rest, api, docusignapi

I am trying to search for a list of envelopes in Docusign with the similar title/name. Is there a way to do this in REST API? The closest i can find is the SearchFolder API but it seems like it only allow to specify dates, folders (Draft,Sent etc) without a way to search by title.

Comment: I don't think they have an option for that. As an alternative: You can pull all documents and save the names on your database. Later when a user is searching for a document, they use your database to look up the name.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do that using the v2.1 API.
See here https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search
using the search_taxt query parameter you can search for a specific text.

```
GET
/v2.1/accounts/4644/envelopes?search_text=Tabs&from_date=2019-03-04T00:00:00.000Z&to_date=2019-03-07T00:00:00.000Z
```